# ng-click event is not firing on span element

Tags: angularjs

Why is the ng-click not working in the code below?
It should be simple. What am I missing.
Thanks

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
    // Set up the app.
    var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

    // Create a controller.
    mainApp.controller('navController', ['$scope', '$log' ,function($scope, $log) {
        //$scope.firstName= "John";
        //$scope.lastName= "Doe";,
        $scope.openTab = function (tabNumber) {
            $log.log(tabNumber);
        };

        var s =1;
    }]);
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/app/app.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />

    </head>
    <body ng-app="mainApp">
        <div class="navigation" ng-controller="navController as nc">
            <!--<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
            <p ng-bind="name"></p>
            <p>{{name}}</p>
            -->
            <span ng-click="nc.openTab(1)" class="btn"> tab 1</span>
            <span ng-click="nc.openTab(2)" class="btn"> tab 2</span>
            <span ng-click="nc.openTab(3)" class="btn"> tab 3</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `controllerAs`, you have to bind variables and methods directly to the controller instance, `this`, instead of `$scope`.

```
// this.firstName = "John";
// this.lastName = "Doe";
this.openTab = function (tabNumber) {
    $log.log(tabNumber);
};
```

Because the `controllerAs` sets the controller instance, `this` in the controller function, to `$scope.nc`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `$scope` in the controller but in the view you are using `as` .

If you want to use `as` badly then your method in controller should be using `this` keyword

Like this

```
this.openTab = function (tabNumber) {
    $log.log(tabNumber);
};
```

But if want to use controller scope then your view should be

```
<span ng-click="openTab(1)" class="btn"> tab 1</span>
<span ng-click="openTab(2)" class="btn"> tab 2</span>
<span ng-click="openTab(3)" class="btn"> tab 3</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This..

```
    (function() {
    'use strict';
    // Set up the app.
    var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

    // Create a controller.
    mainApp.controller('navController', ['$scope', '$log' ,function($scope, $log) {
        //$scope.firstName= "John";
        //$scope.lastName= "Doe";,
        $scope.openTab = function (tabNumber) {
            $log.log(tabNumber);
        };

        var s =1;
    }]);
    }());


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/app/app.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />

    </head>
    <body ng-app="mainApp">
        <div class="navigation" ng-controller="navController">
            <!--<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
            <p ng-bind="name"></p>
            <p>{{name}}</p>
            -->
            <span ng-click="openTab(1)" class="btn"> tab 1</span>
            <span ng-click="openTab(2)" class="btn"> tab 2</span>
            <span ng-click="openTab(3)" class="btn"> tab 3</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I realise this is an old answer, but don't expect people to pay attention if you don't give any explanation about what you've done to fix the problem.